# finfo_file() returning MIME type as 'application/octet-stream' for a .pdf

Tags: php, mime-types, file-type

I'm having an issue with the media uploader in my WordPress site.

For PDFs, the uploaded tells me that the upload has been rejected due to file type.

I have tracked it down to `wp_check_filetype_and_ext()` function in wp-includes/functions.php.

The bit of this function that is casuing the issue is:

```
$finfo = finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
$real_mime = finfo_file( $finfo, $file ); // $file is tmp name
finfo_close( $finfo );
// If the extension does not match the file's real type, return false.
if ( $real_mime !== $type ) {
    $type = $ext = false;
}
```

My problem is that $real_mime does not equal $type (which is the type taken from the extension).

`$real_mime` is being set to `application/octet-stream` for .pdf files.

Any ideas? My server is apache and php is 5.3.

PS: I've copied the whole site on to another server at a different hosting company and it all works fine there, so it seems to be an issue with the live site's hosting.

Thanks

Comment: you are accessing to pipe info, there is needed a event that tell you is onload file. Is my idea of would be happens

Comment: Currently I am in the same process of dealing with PDF Files recognized as application/octet-stream. Although not all are seen as octet-stream only compressed PDF files. Non-compressed are recognized as application/pdf.
Not a solution per se but perhaps a pointer for others.